# When I Click Submit Button Content Dissapears PHP

Tags: php

I made a real basic PHP app when I clicked submit It supposed to print the value of a textbox, and it did but the submit button and textbox disappeared.

Here is my index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>PHP</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <form action="php.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="namee" placeholder="Name">
        <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
    </form>
    
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my php.php:

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST["namee"];
    echo $name;
?>
```

Comment: What result are you expecting?

Comment: If you're getting a blank screen, then PHP is not running on your server.

Comment: Test with this: `<?php echo "PHP is running!"; ?>` -- if it doesn't appear, then PHP is not enabled.

Answer (score 0):

If you expect the submitted value to appear on your current page, change index.php to this, note that as it is stated in the comments, you can ommit the `<?=$_SERVER["PHP_SELF]?>`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>PHP</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <form action="<?=$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="namee" placeholder="Name">
        <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
    </form>
 <?php
    if(isset($_POST["namee"])){
      echo $_POST["namee"];
    }
?>
    
</body>
</html>
```

This will show the value of the submitted form. If you want to show it without changing the current page, you need to look into AJAX.

if your page is blank, make sure that your server is interpret php pages normally, maybe by changing the php tags to `<?php print_r($_POST)  ?>`

Comment: Don't use `action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>"`, just use `action=""` to submit back to itself. But that aside, if the PHP alone yields nothing, then changing the PHP won't change the nothing.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol correct. but If the OP is expecting the text to appear on the current page, then sending it to a separate script will not be the answer, unless that does something and sends a redirect to the original page